# speed up loop - Assigning Values to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops

i have a function that is running a little too slow for my liking and cannot seem to make it faster. I have a combination of 57 products and 402 stores. the function below creates dataframe with products as the index and stores as a columns. The objective is to fetch the max quanty sold by product and store and assign it to the "unconstraintload_df" dataframe. it seems to be doing the job, but it takes an awful amount of time to complete. Does anyone have any ideas to speed it up, please?

```
def getmaxsaleperproduct_and_store(product,store):
    return training_DS[(training_DS["Prod Code"]==product)&(training_DS["Store"]==store)]["Sold Qty"].max()

def unconstraintsales():
    global unconstraintload_df

    ProdCodeList = training_DS["Prod Code"].unique()
    StoreNumberList = training_DS["Store"].unique()

    unconstraintload_df = pd.DataFrame(index=StoreNumberList,columns=ProdCodeList)

    for store in StoreNumberList:
        for prod in ProdCodeList:
            unconstraintload_df.loc[unconstraintload_df.index==store,prod] = getmaxsaleperproduct_and_store(prod,store)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) and avoid nested loops. Remember aggregations in Pandas rarely requires looping unlike general purpose Python using lists, tuples, or dictionaries:

```
unconstraintload_df = pd.pivot_table(training_DS, index="Prod Code", columns="Store", 
                                     values="Sold Qty", aggfunc="max")
```

Additionally, wide datasets beyond reporting tend to be less useful than long format. Consider long form aggregation with `groupby` and avoid 400+ columns to manage:

```
long_agg_df = training_DS.groupby(["Prod Code", "Store"])["Sold Qty"].max()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
unconstraintload_df = training_DS[["Store", "Prod Code", "Sold Qty"]].groupby(["Store", "Prod Code"]).max().reset_index()
```